local version of Stokes theorem
Let $M$ be an oriented n-manifold, and suppose Stokes theorem holds for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{H}^n$ (closed upper-half space), i.e. for any n-1 form $\omega$ with compact support:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}d\omega=0 \ \text{and} \ \int_{\mathbb{H}^n}d\omega=\int_{\partial\mathbb{H}^n}\omega
$$
I'm wondering why this implies that for any chart $(U,\phi)$ of $M$ and n-1 form $\omega$ with compact support in $U$:
$$
\int_U d\omega=\int_{\partial U}d\omega
$$
This is the local version of stokes theorem, and the crucial equality for the proof is
$$
\int_{\phi(U)}d\left( (\phi^{-1})^*\omega \right)=\int_{\partial\phi(U)}\left((\phi^{-1})^*\omega\right)
$$
The author says that this is because stokes theorem holds for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{H}^n$. But here $\phi(U)$ is just an open subset, how can this be applied?

If $U$ is open in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\omega$ is a form on $U$ with compact support, then you can extend it to a smooth form, $\zeta$, on all of $\Bbb{R}^n$ by setting it $0$ elsewhere. Clearly $\zeta$ has compact support as well. Apply the Stokes theorem on $\Bbb{R}^n$ to $\zeta$ and conclude the result for $\omega$ on $U$. Similar remark if $U$ is open in $\Bbb{H}^n$.
